# Create a gif from the recent 10 images in a folder?

Tags: imagemagick, gif

I am wondering if there is a way to create a GIF using ImageMagick or other tools by considering only the recent 10 images from a folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ImageMagick package.

Install it using the command:

`sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

and convert them using this command

`convert -delay 20 -loop 0 ls -1t | head -10 *.jpg myimage.gif`

or

`convert -delay 20 -loop 0 ls -v | head -10 *.jpg myimage.gif`